# Chaining requests in Retrofit + RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have 2 APIs that I want to make request to in sequence and store their data in SQLite.

First I want to make request to API `A` and store its data in SQL table `a`. Then make request to API `B` and store its data in table `b` and some data in table `a_b`. The data stored in `a_b` is from request `B` alone.

How can I do this using RxJava. I read somewhere about using flatMap for this, something like this

```
apiService.A()
    // store in DB here? How? maybe use map()?
    .flatMap(modelA -> {
        // or maybe store modelA in DB here?
        return apiService.B().map(modelB -> {
            storeInDB()l // store B here ?
            return modelB;
        });
    });
```

If I wasn't using lambda functions, this would look as ugly as normal nested calls. Is this a better way to do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I don't think using `map` operator is the best way to go with things like storing the result of the api call.

What I like to do is to separate those things inside `doOnNext` operators. So your example would be something like this:

```
apiService.A()
        .doOnNext(modelA -> db.store(modelA))
        .flatMap(modelA -> apiService.B())
        .doOnNext(modelB -> db.store(modelB));
```

(add necessary `observeOn` and `subscribeOn` yourself, exactly like you need them)

Comment: I didn't know about `do` operators of Rx. After reading its docs, isn't `doOnComplete` a better function for this?

Comment: @Sourabh it depends on your `Observable`. If `onComplete` is called after a successful call from api, then yes. If your `Observable` can emit multiple events, then you should go for `doOnNext`. In your case (`Retrofit`) using `doOnNext` and `doOnComplete` will have the same result, but indeed `doOnComplete` might be a bit more intuitive (I used `doOnNext` out of pure habit).

Comment: I meant, use `doOnComplete` instead of `flatMap`

Comment: ... as `B()` doesn't depend on result of `A()` (SO's 5 min comment edit time)

Comment: using `doOnComplete` instead of `flatMap` would be wrong, because `doOnComplete` wouldn't change the `Observable` in stream, and `flatMap` would. In other words, if you use `flatMap` you can use just one `subscribe`, and trying to use `doOnComplete` instead of this would force you to call `apiService.B().subscribe(...)` inside this `doOnComplete` (which would look ugly as hell)

Comment: Use this for a Single:
`.doOnEvent { t1, t2 ->  }`

Answer (score 24):

Yes, you can use flatmap for this exact purpose. See the below example (Assuming your service A returns `Observable<FooA>` and service B returns `Observable<FooB>`)

```
api.serviceA()
        .flatMap(new Func1<FooA, Observable<FooB>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<FooB> call(FooA fooA) {
                // code to save data from service A to db

                // call service B
                return api.serviceB();
            }
         })
         .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe(new Subscriber<FooB>() {
             @Override
             public void onCompleted() {
             }

             @Override
             public void onError(Throwable e) {

             }

             @Override
             public void onNext(FooB fooB) {
                 // code to save data from service B to db

             }
        });
```

Comment: If I write code to save data to DB in onNext it will run on main thread right? How to save data to db on background thread instead?

Comment: throw in another `flatMap` operator. `api.serviceA().flatMap((FooA) -> {// call service B}).flatMap((FooB) -> {// save data from service B and return a observable stating success / failure}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).doOnNext((isSuccess) -> {// Only this will execute on main thread})`

Comment: How would you do this in RxJava2?