# Rx Java and Retrofit api call for each item of previous call

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, rx-java

I have this API interface

```
@GET("api/..../{commentId}")
Observable<DiscussionPostRoot> getCommentsInPost(@Path("commentId") String commentId)
```

DiscussionPostRoot has some field and List of object, for each object of this list I want to call the same API call but with different values. For this moment I was doing `foreach` but API results come in different time and my adapter get random values. What to do ;) ? I prefer answers without lambda but anyway there can be lambda :)

Comment: Can you please show what it looks like currently? I'm not entirely clear I understand your description/requirement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining requests in Retrofit + RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785090/chaining-requests-in-retrofit-rxjava)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RxJava (and judging by the Observable in your API, you are), you can solve it with some stream manipulation like this:

https://gist.github.com/tnovoselec/73ba4946d4116e8f05946b5e40a3a031

Anyway, the point is to first pull the root object, then create a new stream from it (first flatmap), then for each object create a new observable to pull comment (second flatmap), and finally collect everything into one list which can be passed to your adapter.

Also, don't forget to add proper observeOn() call, to get your results on UI thread.