# How to send requset after another one in OkHTTP3?

Tags: android, okhttp

How to send requset after another one use OkHTTP3 ? 
I have to to this:
1) I send request1 using method `OkHTTPRequest` , to server 2)Server send response with COOKIE for request1 3) I save this cookies 4) i send request2 with saved cookies.

I have a problem on step 4.
It seems that request2 send just after request1 , before request1 saved his cookies.
How to resolve it?
I want send reuest2 just after request save his own cookie.

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        try
        {
            // Получаем cookie и авторизируемся
            Log.d("TAG", "Вызываем  OkHTTPRequest1");
            OkHTTPRequest(postUrl, "POST", postData1);
            Log.d("TAG", "Вызываем  OkHTTPRequest2");
            OkHTTPRequest(postUrl2, "PUT", postData2);

            int a;
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    // Сохраняем cookieFromServer
    public void saveCookie(List<Cookie> cookies)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++)
        {
            String str = cookies.get(i).toString();
            if (str.indexOf("issa7=") != -1)
            {
                cookieFromServer.add(cookies.get(i));
                Log.d("TAG", "Сохраняем cookie в глобальную переменную  ="+ cookies.get(i).toString());
            }
        }
    }

    // Создаем клиент OkHTTPRequest и обрабатываем запросы
    void OkHTTPRequest(String postUrl, String requestMethodType, String postData) throws IOException, JSONException
    {
        // Создаем клиент OkHTTPRequest
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient()
                .newBuilder()
                // Переопределяем методы чтобы можно было сохранять и применять ccokie в запросах
                .cookieJar(new CookieJar()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies)
                    {
                        saveCookie(cookies);
                        Log.d("TAG", "Вызываем  saveCookie ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url)
                    {
                        Log.d("TAG","Читаем cookie");
                        return cookieFromServer;
                    }
                })
                .build();

        Log.d("TAG","Создаем OkHttpClient клиента " + client.toString());

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, postData);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(postUrl)
                .method(requestMethodType, body)
                .addHeader("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4")
                .addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
                .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
                .addHeader("User-Agent", "Mango Mobile Android")
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e)
            {
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
            {
                // Получать response.body().string() можно только один раз. Иначе будет ошибка так реализованно.
                String html = response.body().string();
                //Log.d("TAG", "Код сайта "+ html);
                Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
                // Копируем содержание response.body()
                setDoc(doc);
                parseResult(bids);
                // Чтобы обращаться к компанентам из MainActivity нужно использовать runOnUiThread
                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        // Отключаем progressBar
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        // Устанавливаем адаптер
                        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, feedsList);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });


            }
        });
    }

    // Сохраняем Document код страницы
    void setDoc(Document doc)
    {
        this.doc = doc;
        // Получаем список БИДОВ
        Log.d("TAD", "Получаем список БИДОВ");
        Elements tmpBids = doc.select("a.go-product[href$=\"vats\"]");

        for (int i = 0; i < tmpBids.size(); i++)
        {
            bids.add(tmpBids.get(i).attr("href"));
            //Log.d("TAD", bids.get(i).toString());
        }
    }


    private void parseResult(List<String> bids)
    {
        // Формируем данные feedsList для адаптера
        Log.d("TAD", "Формируем данные feedsList для адаптера");
        feedsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bids.size(); i++)
        {
            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setTitle(bids.get(i));
            item.setThumbnail("thumbnail");
            feedsList.add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Checkout RxJava it has Observables using which you can make chain of requests

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. Method names should be lowercase (Stylistic) `OkHTTPRequest(...)` was a little confusing at first.
2. You are firing the HTTP requests asynchronously you can either force the HTTP client to block by calling `client.newCall(request).execute()` I believe or as the others have suggested use a library like RxJava to handle chaining async commands.
3. `OkHttpClient` is meant to be reused for multiple requests especially when using a cookie jar. Ideally you only have one instance of the `OkHttpClient` and reuse it for multiple requests. Your cookie jar seems like it might work but only because you are using a global list to store cookies which is probably a bad practice.

If you can add the `okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar` dependency you can get a working cookie jar out of the box with the following code.

```
import okhttp3.JavaNetCookieJar;

CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
JavaNetCookieJar cookieJar = new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieManager);

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().cookieJar(cookieJar).build();
```

Also,  anytime you are having trouble debugging with `OkHttp` its nice to set up an [OkHttp Logging Interceptor](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/okhttpclient-logging-configuration-with-interceptors).

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor logging =
    new HttpLoggingInterceptor((msg) -> {
        Log.d(msg);
    });
logging.setLevel(Level.BODY);

client.addNetworkInterceptor(logging);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) . It is a great REST client for Android and Java, built on top of OkHttp. It makes working with RxJava a pleasure.

Here's a helpful post that can give you a bit more context on how to chain your requests with Retrofit and RxJava [helpful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785090/chaining-requests-in-retrofit-rxjava)