# How to perform n calls sequentially with RxJava2 and Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

So following scenario:
I have a dynamic arraylist with f.e. ids. And i want to do for every id in this list a request to an api. The following requests should only start, when the previous request got an successful answer. So no asncy reqeusts.
Is there any pretty way to receive this with retrofit and rxjava.

I have one solution with a recursively function:

```
foo(int position, List<Int> idList, ApiController controller){
  if(idList.size() < position){
    //execute finish
  }else{
  controller.postRequest().subscribe(()->{
    //Request finish. Do next request...
    foo(++position, idList, controller);});
}
```

Is there a way to do this in pretty with rxjava2?

I just came up with an asynchronous solution for rxjava2:
(which look good to me, but doesn't full fill the job...

```
Observable.fromIterable(idList).flatMapCompletable(id -> {
controller.doRequests();})
.subscribe(()->{
//Finished all requests. Do stuff
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining requests in Retrofit + RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785090/chaining-requests-in-retrofit-rxjava)

Comment: No there you have always 2 calls. My problem is that i have n calls.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like replacing flatMapCompletable with concatMapCompletable is doing the work.

```
Observable.fromIterable(idList).concatMapCompletable(id -> {
controller.doRequests();})
.subscribe(()->{
//Finished all requests. Do stuff
});
```