# Kotlin how to make multiple API calls using retrofit and rxjava in sequential order?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2

I have an array list of API

```
    allSignsList = ArrayList()
            allSignsList.add(AllSignsList( "Overview", "overview.aspx"))
            allSignsList.add(AllSignsList( "Details", "details.aspx"))
            allSignsList.add(AllSignsList( "Description", "description.aspx"))
            allSignsList.add(AllSignsList( "profile", "profile.aspx"))
```

I am making the request using for loop in the allSignList array since the response format is same in all the API. But the main problem that I am facing is the result is not in sequential order. I want to wait for the request to complete before calling another API.

I am making network call this way:

```
try {
        mApiServiceNetwork.getNetworkServiceForXml(getNewXmlBaseUrl())
                .getXmlTest(path)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(object : Subscriber<RSSFeedItems>() {
                    override fun onCompleted() {
                        //Do nothing for now
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onError " + Log.getStackTraceString(e))
                        apiResult.onAPIFail()
                    }

                    override fun onNext(rssFeed: RSSFeedItems) {
                        Log.e(TAG+" Weekly", (MainActivity.weeklyCount++).toString() + " Operation performed successfully")
                        apiResult.onModel(rssFeed)

                    }
                })

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception" + Log.getStackTraceString(e))
        apiResult.onError(e)
    }
```

Comment: you can do this using kotlin coroutine

Comment: could you please elaborate more on that as I am new to kotlin

Comment: see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36474120/how-to-make-multiple-request-and-wait-until-data-is-come-from-all-the-requests-i

Comment: I have already commented on that post as well because the correct answer is not checked

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785090/chaining-requests-in-retrofit-rxjava