# RXAndroid/RXJava2: Chain three retrofit requests and repeat the same process again

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java2, rx-android

I have stared learning RxAndroid and have understood the reactive programming approach and power of different operators like flatmap, map, and xmap.

I have the following situation, I have a list of Reports say `List<Reports>` (obtained at runtime). I have to make 3 API calls for a report in a *sequence* (API 1 -> API 2 -> API 3) and repeat the same process for all reports in a sequence.

**Example**:
For Reports `A`, `B`, `C,` and `D` in `List<Reports>` make 3 API call for `A` and then for `B` and then for `C` and then for `D`. If anyone of 3 API calls fails for a report then stop the remaining call and continue for the next Report. Here the size of `List<Reports>` is known at runtime only.

How can I use RXjava to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you checked out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785090/chaining-requests-in-retrofit-rxjava

Comment: yes, I have checked it. The condition of repeating the process again is not present in that scenario.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Comment: I did get that, thats why I deleted that comment. My bad

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi I do not have code in form of RXjava. I have provided a clear representation of the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have the 4 API calls, a `combineLatest` operation would ideally return type `Reports`.

```
Observable<Report> result = Observable.combineLatest(
                apiA,
                apiB,
                apiC,
                apiD,
                (respA, respB, respC, respD) -> respA + respB + respC + respD
        )
                .subscribeOn(
                ....
```

To be able to achieve the sequential order, you will need to wrap them in a `flatMap` operation:

```
Observable o = Observable.just(.....)// your initial data
o
  .flatMap(value -> doCombineLatestOperation(value))
  .subscribe(resp -> //Deal with data);
```

Hope that helps.